# How can I change the default track of an html5 video element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

My page contains this `<video>` tag with several subtitle `<track>`s. I would like to enable on the fly the track by clicking on the corresponding national flag using jquery:

```
  <div id="lang">
    <img src="mini/ita.png" class="it" alt="Italiano" title="Italiano" />
    <img src="mini/eng.png" class="en" alt="English"  title="English"  />        
  </div>


<video controls="controls" >

  <source src="webcast.webm" />
  <source src="webcast.mp4"  />
  <source src="webcast.ogv"  />

  <track kind="subtitles" src="./sub-en.vtt" srclang="en" />
  <track kind="subtitles" src="./sub-it.vtt" srclang="it" />

</video>

<script>
$('#lang img').click(function(){
    language=$(this).attr('class');

    $('video track').removeAttr('default');
    $('video track[srclang='+language+']').attr('default','default');
});
</script>
```

The "default" attribute is correctly inserted, but no subtitle is displaied. Manually inserting the default attribute works perfectly (on chrome and opera).

Comment: By the time you set the default flag in from js, a the browser has likely already chosen a default. You may try seting the textTrack.mode property to "showing" on the desired track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$('#lang img').click(function(){
    var language=$(this).attr('class');

    $($('video').prop('textTracks')).prop('mode', function(){
        return this.language == language ? 'showing' : 'disabled';
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is very cumbersome. Your linked example **does not start** on chromium 22; **show subs** in firefox 17; **does not show subs** in opera 12. 
[My example](http://ross.iasfbo.inaf.it/~gloria/eclipse/test.html), built using your suggestions, does not work on all the three.

Comment: About Chrome: Chrome has sometimes problems with mp4 playback (often after installing IE10RC), I switched to webm. Opera 12.1 obviously has a bug to access the textTrack object through the track element. I altered my code, to access it over the textTracks property. In Chrome you have to enable track support via about:flags. In FF and IE, I'm using a polyfill. My example should now work in all browsers (But I hate Opera).

Comment: Thanking your help, now it works.  Chrome tracks via about:flags were already enabled. **For all browsers, chrome included, the problem was solved using the scripts modernizer.js and polyfill.js you suggested**, even if I have on the console the error `set the mime-type of your WebVTT files to text/vtt`. I took the liberty to modify your sample code here above, if you like my edits. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lang img').click(function(){
    language=your value;
    $('#yourID').attr('srclang', language); 
 });
```

Do like this..